# Trying to understand Weak Topology and Weak* Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

(1) The Weak Topology on $E$ is defined as the topology on $E$ with respect to the mappings $f:E \to \mathbb K$, $f \in E^*$. It is denoted $\sigma(E,E^*)$.

(2) The Weak* topology on $E^*$ is the topology on $E^*$ with respect to the mappings $x̂ : E^* \to \mathbb K$, where $x̂ (l) = l(x)$, $l \in E^*$. It is denoted by $\sigma(E^*,E)$.

Now I want to write them down explicitly:

(1) $\gamma_f := \{f^{-1}(V): V $ open in  $\mathbb K\}$,
$\gamma := \bigcup_{f \in E^*} \gamma_{f}$,

(2) $\chi_{x̂ } := \{x̂ ^{-1}(V): V $ open in $\mathbb K$ }

$\chi := \bigcup_{x̂  \in E^{**}} \chi_{x̂ }$.

Question: Are $\sigma(E^*,E)$ and $\sigma(E,E^*)$ the smallest topology containing $\gamma$ and $\chi$ respectively?

Comment: Yes, They are. That is how they are defined

Comment: Not that $E^{**}$ doesn't make any sense here !

Comment: Maybe you should write 
$$\chi := \bigcup_{x̂  \in E^{**}:\; x̂(f) = f(x)} \chi_{x̂ }$$ to point out that $x̂$ is not an arbitrary element of $E^{**}$

Comment: Yes you are right ....
But I would prefer write $(E^*)'$ indicating the set of all linear function on $E^*$.

 What do you mean by $E^{**}$ ?

Comment: The bidual space, i.e. the space of all linear and continuous functionals $f: E^* \to \mathbb K$.

Comment: What does continuous mean for a function defined on $E^*$?

Note that you don't have any topology on $E^*$ before defining weak^* topology...

Comment: If $f: E^{*} \to \mathbb K$, $x \in E^*$ and $|f(x)| \le c||x||$ for some c > 0, I can use that continuity is equivalent to boundedness for linear operators. Note that ||.|| is the operator norm.

Comment: In the case $E$ is normable, yes we automatically have a norm and consequently a topology on $E^*$ . However if we consider a broad setting topological vector space $E$  then $E**$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Redshoes You are right. Forgot to say the we only consider normed spaces.